# Check Validation for DateTime upto 6 month past

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I want to check the Date and Time which I have entered in my input field (html) so such that these entries are not older than 6 months prior to current date & time. How would we validate this condition?

Comment: First try it yourself and show where you are getting the problem

Comment: Validate where. Client?, Server?  In JAVA?, in PHP?

Comment: I want Logic in java script

Comment: So tag it JavaScript (I just did it for you), then add the code and HTML you have tried and ask specific questions. Also you can generate a date picker that does not allow older dates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, Date Validation function in javascript

```
function dateValidation() {
        var b = new Date("2014/01/22"); //your input date here

        var d = new Date(); // today date
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 6);  //subtract 6 month from current date 

        if (b > d) {
            alert("date is less than 6 month");
        } else {
            alert("date is older than 6 month");
        }
    }
```